# Stop msw fron showing warnings about unhandled request?

Tags: msw

Is there any way to configure msw to only intercept requests to paths with certain pattern?

For example only paths start with "/api".

Currently it shows warning every time I navigate to some page of my React app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
worker.start({
  onUnhandledRequest(req, print) {
    if (req.url.pathname.startsWith('/api/') {
      print.warning()
    }

    return;
  }
})
```

If you want to turn it off completely use:

```
worker.start({
  onUnhandledRequest: 'bypass',
})
```

Comment: This was very unclear in the doc and took me days to figure it out. Thanks though.